# Create SQL Server CE database file programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, database, sql-server-ce

How can I create a new SQL Server Compact database file (.sdf) programmatically, without having an existing template file to copy from?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

There is some good info here: [Create a SQL Server Compact Edition Database with C#](http://arcanecode.com/2007/01/25/create-a-sql-server-compact-edition-database-with-c/)

```
string connectionString = "DataSource=\"test.sdf\"; Password=\"mypassword\"";
SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
en.CreateDatabase();
```

Comment: Surprisingly, creating a 0-byte file is good enough for SQL CE to start treating it as a database. This is useful for times when you want to use `Path.GetTempFileName()`, which creates a 0-byte file for you.

Comment: the DataSource must be surrounded with double quotes. The password, on the other hand, must be surrounded with single quotes.

Answer (score 9):

First, go click on the Browse tab. Now navigate to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.1`. Now pick the `System.Dadta.SqlServerCe.dll`, click on it, then click on OK to pull in the reference.

Now let’s write some code. First, go to the head of the class, whoops I mean header of your class and let’s create a using reference.

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
using System.IO;

  string connectionString;
  string fileName = "aminescm.sdf";
  string password = “aminescm”;

  if (File.Exists(fileName))
  {
    File.Delete(fileName);
  }

  connectionString = string.Format(
    "DataSource=\"{0}\"; Password='{1}'", fileName, password);
  SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
  en.CreateDatabase();
```

You can find more and more about this, it's really an amazing web site:

http://arcanecode.com/arcane-lessons/

Comment: Now you can just add a reference to the NuGet package for SqlCe instead of referencing a local assembly.

Comment: it's `System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`, you have a typo there in the third sentence