# SQL Server CE: Generate DB with script

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, asp.net-3.5

I would like to use the `SqlCeEngine` class to build a database and populate it with tables ([like this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487845/create-sql-server-ce-database-file-programmatically)) but using a script generated by [ExportSqlCE](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/).

I was wondering if this was possible using `SqlBulkCopy`? (A SQL Server CE version which has been replicated [here](http://sqlcebulkcopy.codeplex.com/)).

Or if there is another solution to quickly populating a `.sdf` database file with tables and constraints (28 tables, 52 constraints, most columns cannot be null).

When my application loads I check to see if the database file exists. In the eventuality that this file is missing (or when the program is loaded for the first time after installation) I want to be able to re-generate an empty database.

I created the database using [DataPort Console](http://primeworks-mobile.com/Products/DataPortConsole.html) because as its my first real database application I wanted to design the database graphically.

Comment: Why not simply include an empty database file with your application, and copy it to the desired location if required?

Comment: In the event the Database file is lost I want the the application to be able to maintain itself.

Comment: Yes, my proposal will allow you to do that...

Comment: This does not solve my issue as later I want to have the option of altering the database. I want to have the ability to give the user an updated version of the application that may need to re-build the database. I would like the option of extracting their data, deleting the database, rebuilding with a new schema and then importing their data under the guise of "Program Initialization After Installation" so that they cannot see changes. I'd rather not have to provide a new Database (even if its empty) whenever I change things

Comment: OK, now you explain your requirements! - You should provide ALTER TABLE/CREATE TABLE scripts with the updated app, and maybe store the current database version in a database table.

Comment: Just tested some create table scripts in an app to see how this can be handled. Just gonna have to populate a List of strings and then run the SqlCeCommand for each element. I hadn't considered recording database version yet so that's something I'll add to the design.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I was not able to find a solution that replicated my desired functionality and instead, following the advice of [ErikEJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183934/erikej) decided to implement a series of scripts to be run on load. The [ExportSqlCE](http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com/) is still useful for creating scripts of an already defined  `SQL Server CE database`.

I eventually implemented a `List<string>` in which I added the various scripts. This allows me the option of loading scripts if I want to update a Database or choosing hardcoded "default" scripts for the initial version of a database. I could then loop around the List elements  changing the `SqlCeCommand command.CommandText` property to the next element in the List.